# How to make edit/add/delete items from Datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding

How to make edit/add/delete items from Datagrid 
I have implemented it using Data Table

```
        DataTable _datatable = new DataTable();
        DataRow _datarow;
```

I have initiated data here , I wonder to ask , how can I modify this data 
How to get values from the datagrid and interact with it 
.
 List list = _datatable.AsEnumerable().ToList();

I have converted it to List , and I get the data from there  ? Is it a good idea .

I want to be able to Update, Insert and Delete from.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont do mvvm you can simply set the itemsSource of the Datagrid to your datatable

```
 this.dgMyDataGridControl.ItemsSource= this._mydatatable;
```

and dont forget to set the properties for your datagrid to what you want (CanUserAddRows, ...)

thats of course just update, delete and modify data in your datatable and not database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple List of objects. Then create a DataGrid and bind a DataRecordList to it.
Frontend should look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="TestDataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Data="clr-namespace:TestDataGrid"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Data:DataRecordList x:Key="DataSource"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DataCollection" Source="{StaticResource DataSource}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="GridData"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataCollection}}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserAddRows="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="SomeValue" Binding="{Binding Path=SomeValue}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind like this:

```
namespace TestDataGrid
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class DataRecord
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataRecordList : List<DataRecord>
    {
        public DataRecordList()
        {
            this.Add(new DataRecord() { ID = 1, Name = "Johnny", SomeValue = "Dummy" });
            this.Add(new DataRecord() { ID = 2, Name = "Grace", SomeValue = "Foo" });
            this.Add(new DataRecord() { ID = 3, Name = "Steve", SomeValue = "Bar" });
        }
    }
}
```

You can add rows, delete rows and even edit rows as well as sort and reorder columns.
Enjoy.
JiKra